# Show 2 Recent Blog Posts in 2 Columns on Homepage in (WordPress)

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to show 2 latest blog posts on my homepage.

However, I want them to appear in 2 separate boxes. This code only shows the same blog post twice. How do I get the second most recent blog post to show in my second box?

Any help would be much appreciated :)

```html
      <div class="row boxesl">
            <div class="c6">
           
                            
            <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=1' ); ?>
            
            <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

           <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?></p>
 
           <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
                        
                  </div>
      



      <div class="c6 last">
          
            <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=1' ); ?>
            
            <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

           <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?></p>
 
           <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            
          
          </div>
```

Comment: It worked or not?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `offset` parameter to arguments.

```
<div class="row boxesl">
        <div class="c6">


        <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=1' ); ?>

        <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

       <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
             <p><?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?></p>

       <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

              </div>




  <div class="c6 last">

        <?php $the_query = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=1&offset=1' ); ?>

        <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

       <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
             <p><?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?></p>

       <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>


      </div>
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: Thank you so much! Although I realised that offset showed the 3rd recent blog post but when I set the offset=1 it did it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Below Code :

```
<div class="row boxesl">                     
<?php 
    $the_query = new WP_Query( array(
                                        'post_status' => 'publish',
                                        'orderby' => 'publish_date',
                                        'order' => 'DESC',
                                        'posts_per_page' => 2) 
                             ); 
    if($the_query->have_posts())
    {
        $cnt=1;
        while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); 
            if($cnt==2)
                $class=" last";
            else
                 $class="";
?>
        <div class="c6 <?php echo $class;?>"> 
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
        <p><?php the_excerpt(__('(more…)')); ?></p>
        </div>
<?php 
        $cnt++;
        endwhile; 
        wp_reset_postdata(); 
    }
?>
```